# How to load audio file into html page

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

I have backend with `flask` and for frontend I used `javascript-html`, when I use `postman` or `insomnia` and send the request to get the audio file it's working and it show the audio file and I can play it, but when I try to use it on `HTML-javascript` not working

this is my `flask` part

```
@app.route('/g-media', methods=['POST'])
def get_media():
    file = request.get_json()['id']
    dict_data = get_media_path(file)
    return send_file(dict_data['path'], mimetype="audio/wav", as_attachment=True)
```

and this is my `javascript` part

```
async function get_selected_detail(audio_id) {
    var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/g-media';
    var data = JSON.stringify({"id": audio_id});
    var header = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    let result = await axios.post(url, data, { headers: header }).then(res => {
    console.log(typeof(res.data))
```

this is `HTML` part

```
<audio controls>
    <source type="audio/mpeg" id="audio-ource">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "source" tag expects src which is a path to the target file/input you need to create a URL while uploading the file and send that URL back via get call.
i.e. <source type="audio/mpeg" src="path to your file" id="audio-ource"/ >